# PM2 watch only in dev mode

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm running a node.js app and using pm2 for startup.
For pm2 i have created a process.json file to define my app and two enviroments (prod and dev).

For dev mode i want to enable the watch option of pm2, but not in prod mode.

But i see no way to define this.
Either this option is activated in both modes or in none of them.

Can you please help me to do this?

```
{
"apps": [{
    "name": "myapp",
    "script": "./app.js",
    "watch": ["public", "views"],
    "env": {
        "LOGLEVEL": "debug",
        "LOGFILE": "debug.log"
    },
    "env_production": {
        "LOGLEVEL": "info",
        "LOGFILE": "info.log"
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: can you explain in more details your problem and what you tried

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pm2-dev` which is included with pm2.

Simply remove the `watch` tag in your `ecosystem.json` or set it to `false`.

And then:

```sh
# Start in development env
pm2-dev ecosystem.json

# Start in production env
pm2 start ecosystem.json --env production
```

With `pm2-dev` watch mode is automatically enabled, and it is not with `pm2 start`.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This solution does not seem to work 100% of the time. Likely depending on setup**

Watch can be specified in the env configuration:

```
{
"apps": [{
    "name": "myapp",
    "script": "./app.js",
    "env": {
        "watch": ["public", "views"],
        "LOGLEVEL": "debug",
        "LOGFILE": "debug.log",

    },
    "env_production": {
        "watch": false,
        "LOGLEVEL": "info",
        "LOGFILE": "info.log"
    }
}]
}
```

The sequence I tested this with:

1. `pm2 start ecosystem.json` -> watch enabled
2. `pm2 delete 0` -> need to delete the app to change environment
3. `pm2 start ecosystem.json --env production` -> watch disabled

Comment: This didn't work for me. It would only watch for changes, if I put the watch command **outside** of the "env" hash (thus forcing me to watch in both dev and production environments). Eventually, I ended up rolling with [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and the nodemon `--watch` option instead.

Comment: This does work. Did you notice that the watch value had and array of paths what to watch, which likely didn't match yours. If this is the case just set it to `"watch": true` to watch everything and try again

Comment: no, it does _not_ work, you can use `env*` only for environment variables https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2264

Comment: Interesting. It seems then to work sometimes and sometimes not, In that thread it is working for the guy in the last comment. Likely something changed on the way.